Mailing error: Expected a string or file resource
I am getting the above error message when trying to send a quick email to less then 50 contacts via extended search. I setup the outgoing email as SMTP + sender address and was able to send a test email. I didn't configure any crons yet because I thought that was only required for CiviMail but maybe I'm wrong. Any help appreciated...
Stacktrace top:
[error] Mailing error: #0 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(945): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#1 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct('Expected a stri...', NULL, 16, Array, NULL)
#2 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(236): PEAR::_raiseError(NULL, 'Expected a stri...')
#3 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/net_smtp/Net/SMTP.php(1220): PEAR::__callStatic('raiseError', Array)
#4 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/mail/Mail/smtp.php(391): Net_SMTP->data(NULL, 'MIME-Version: 1...')
#5 /opt/drupal/vendor/pear/mail/Mail/smtp.php(319): Mail_smtp->send_or_fail(Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Mail/FilteredPearMailer.php(77): Mail_smtp->send(Array, Array, NULL)
#7 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Mail.php(208): CRM_Utils_Mail_FilteredPearMailer->send(Array, Array, NULL)
#8 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php(934): CRM_Utils_Mail::send(Array)
#9 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php(797): CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email->sendMessage('"CiviCRM" <vern...', '5', 'Test', '', '', 'jan.ciriack@pos...', 539, Array, '', '')
#10 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php(388): CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email->sendEmail('', '', '"CiviCRM" <vern...', Array, '', '', '', NULL, NULL)
#11 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php(336): CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email->submit(Array)
#12 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Form.php(646): CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email->postProcess()
#13 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(153): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#14 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(120): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email), 'upload')
#15 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email), 'upload')
#16 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Task_Email), 'upload')
#17 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('upload')
#18 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(325): CRM_Core_Controller->run(Array, Array)
#19 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)
#20 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)
#21 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php(88): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)
#22 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php(83): Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke(Array)
#23 [internal function]: Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main(Array, '')


Quick email doesn't need cron.  Are there error messages in the log file?

There is only this one liner in the log. Looks like the send call throws an exception:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/a92aacaa76f5018dbe2dcd817a7b9ae0098c06dc/CRM/Utils/Mail.php#L211

You can try adding $e->getTraceAsString() to that line, so that it also logs the stack trace.

I have added the stacktrace above. It doesn't tell me a lot though.

It tells us that $message is the problem var (3 lines up), so then my next step would be to debug what is $message and what is $params['html'], and if it's not obvious from that, then what happens inside self::setEmailHeaders().

Thanks for the hint. The issue is that I'm trying to send an empty body. No problem if I write something in the body. To whom can I address this?

I've put up a PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30172. It worked for me. Can you confirm it also fixes it for you?
Just on line 208 of CRM/Utils/Mail.php, change
$result = $mailer->send($to, $headers, $message);
to
$result = $mailer->send($to, $headers, $message ?? '');

Yes, it's fixed. I wouldn't do the null check inside the send call though, probably inside setEmailHeaders.
